# Why NodeJS says that an Array is an Object?

Tags: node.js

What is wrong on my code?

```
let x = ['hello',1]
let y = [2]
let z = {x:"hello",y:2}
console.log("type of x:",typeof x) // expected array!
console.log("type of y:",typeof y) // expected array!
console.log("type of z:",typeof z) // expected object, ok
```

Result:

```
type of x: object
type of y: object
type of z: object
```

Comment: oops, sorry polluting!  I was thinking in **JSON primitives** instead of Javascript primitives.

Answer (score 2):

Because JavaScript arrays are objects.

You can check whether a value is an array using the `Array.isArray()` function.